# Changing default ftp directories in vsftpd

Tags: unix, ftp, webserver, vsftpd

On my Godaddy dedicated server, I have to FTP files to a defined directory that I cannot change. This means I have to work on files locally, upload them to the FTP directory on the server, then move them to the web directory on the shell.

How (hopefully in the config files, which I have access to) can I change the directory to which I upload the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well despite the fact the question was not programming, here is what I did. Simply create new users with the home directory as the directory you want access to through FTP. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

you can change the local directory in Ftp config file(depends on which FTP you using) 
for example in vsftpd.conf file (/etc/vsftpd.conf)
put this line:

```
local_root=/ftpDirectory
```